# UnicodeDecodeError while Image Processing in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matplotlib

I am working with OpenCV Canny Edge Detection in Python 2.7.12. Upon importing matplotlib I encounter the following error:

```
> **File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 398, in ttfFontProperty
    sfnt4 = sfnt4.decode('ascii').lower()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)**
```

I have hunted for the answer but don't seem to find a solution when dealing with images. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import sys

#read image from file specified
img = cv2.imread('test.tif', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR);

#define display window name
windowname = "Image Segmentation";

#check if image has loaded
if not img is None:
    edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()

    #start the event loop - essential
    #cv2.waitKey() is a keyboard binding function (argument is time in ms).
    #if you press any key in that time, the program continues.
    #if 0 is passed, it waits indefinitely for a key stroke

    key = cv2.waitKey(0);

    #It can also be set to detect specific key strokes by recording which     key is pressed

    if (key == ord('x')):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows();

else:
    print ("No image file successfully loaded");**
```

Comment: where is the rest of Traceback ?

Comment: The traceback is too long and exceeds the character limit here!! Couldn't post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's seems to be non-ASCII attribute in the .tif image (fonts part), which your version of the matplotlib library doesn't support.

In matplotlib package of Python 3.4, I have the following code in `C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py`:

```
if sfnt4:
    sfnt4 = sfnt4.decode('macroman').lower()
```

And decoding a font name containing non-ascii chars work.

EDIT: it seems that you just need to update your matplotlib package:

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

I installed latest matplotlib for python 2.7 (that's dedication :)) and the encoding has been switched to `macroman`, so just upgrading will solve your problem.